# How to print with ionic via bluetooth printer?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm looking for libary for bluetooth print, but i just found this, https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer, this library just support google cloud print.

Any one know how to print via bluetooth printer with ionic?

I'm not yet bought printer cause i'm not sure i can do this.

Any suggest?